# Create a rule, when inputs are not empty

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to do something with jQuery. I'm still learning.

I added the `disabled` class to my button with jQuery and Bootstrap. I also added the `.required` class to my inputs. When my inputs are not empty, I want to remove the `disabled` class for button.

My code:

```
$(".required").each(function() {
    $(".required", Form).blur(function(){
        if ( $(this).val() !== '') {
            $(Button, this).removeClass("disabled");
        } else {
            $(Button, this).addClass("disabled");
        }
    });
});
```

Screenshot: http://prntscr.com/3o0n7k

How can I do it?

Comment: please add some code sample, and tell us exactly the expected result and what happens

Comment: You need to show what you have tried and also explain what you are trying to accomplish. It sounds like you are trying to validate a control which if so you should look into jquery validation (or some other validation library).

Comment: yes sorry. i updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

Use [addClass](http://api.jquery.com/addclass/) and [removeClass](http://api.jquery.com/removeclass/)

and  check ur textbox on either blur or submit

like

```
$('#tb').blur(function(){
if($(this).val()=='')
{
    $('#dv').addClass('hide');

}else
{
    $('#dv').addClass('show');
}

});
```

Comment: good try but is not workin for me.. check this: http://prntscr.com/3o0n7k - i try this code: http://pastebin.com/7NG9LQhR

Comment: @seruves u are putting blur function on ur form .... i think it is not a good way...my code will work for inputs not for form

Answer (score 0):

It depends when do you want to check if the input is empty. If you want to check that while typing you can set a keyup listener to the input element like so:

```
   $('.my-input-class').on('keyup', function() {
       if ($(this).val() !== '') {
          $('.my-button-class').removeClass('disabled');
       }
       else {
          $('.my-button-class').addClass('disabled');
       }
   })
```

If you want your button to update on blur (when leaving input field) then instead of 'keyup' you need to pass 'blur' to on function.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$("#Form").find(".required").each(function() {
     if ($(this).val() !== '') {
        $("#Form button").removeClass('disabled');
     }     
});
```